# How do I create a Regex from a user-provided string which contains regex metacharacters?

Tags: regex, rust

I need to create a regular expression using the `regex` crate which includes a string passed as a command line argument to the program. The command line argument can contain `$` and `{}`.

If I hard code the string as `r"..."`, then it works fine, but if I use the command line argument as `format!(r#"{}"#, arg_str)`, I get the following error (assuming `arg_str` = `${replace}`) :

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Syntax(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
regex parse error:
    ${replace}
      ^
error: decimal literal empty
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
)', libcore/result.rs:945:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Simplified code example to demonstrate this issue:

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
    let ref arg_str = args[1];

    let re = Regex::new(format!(r#"{}"#, arg_str).as_str()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", re);
}
```

If this is run with a simple argument like `replace`, there is no error, but if I pass it something like `${replace}`, I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: I have currently resorted to passing a "pre-escaped" value as an arugment, e.g. `\$\{replace\}`

Comment: It's worth noting that `format!` absolutely does not behave how you appear to think it does.  `"abc"` and `r"abc"` are not different kinds of things; they're both strings.  It's just a question of how the compiler interprets their literal contents at compile time.  Meaning that `format!("{}", ...)` and `format!(r#"{}"#, ...)` do the same thing.  It's also worth noting that `format!("{}", value)` is really just a long-winded way of writing `value.to_string()`.

Comment: I understand now...my (incorrect) assumption was that it would convert it into a raw string since you can pass a raw string to Regex and not worry about escaping characters. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The regex crate has a function `escape` which does what you need.

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/1.0.0/regex/fn.escape.html):

> ## Function `regex::escape`
>
> ```
> pub fn escape(text: &str) -> String
> ```
>
> Escapes all regular expression meta characters in `text`.
>   The string returned may be safely used as a literal in a regular expression.

So passing your `arg_str` through `regex::escape` should fix your problem.