# How to insert a string slice into a raw string?

Tags: regex, string, rust, raw

Whenever provided with **a_new_phone_number** of type &str I want to insert it somehow into a raw string for further input into Regex::new(). Is there a macro similar to format!() for that?

```
phone_number = Regex::new(r"(?xm)^.*{a_new_phone_number}.*$ ").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format!()` for this.

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let a_new_phone_number = "111-222-3333";
    let phone_number = Regex::new(&format!(r"(?m)^.? {}.?$ ", a_new_phone_number)).unwrap();
}
```

Bear in mind that if the regex itself has `{}` characters, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855968/in-rust-how-to-do-replace-all-regex-rep-of-regex-when-rep-contains-some-var) for how to avoid problems. And if the user-provided string is not validated (or even if it is), it should probably be *escaped* as in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196388/how-do-i-create-a-regex-from-a-user-provided-string-which-contains-regex-metacha).